# How do I turn off the beep in the terminal in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I've recently started using a new desktop PC with Ubuntu Linux installed. However the terminal beeps annoyingly. i.e. If I'm at the start of the line and I press Backspace, it'll beep to tell me that there are no characters to delete. Of if I am trying to tab complete and there are no completions for it, then it'll beep.

How do I turn this off?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/275760/4066

Comment: The link given by Raoul says that in the gnome terminal "go to Edit -> Profile Preferences -> General and uncheck the "Terminal bell" checkbox" down below. It's a bit strange that this sound setting is located in a tab called "Text". But it works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As the pc speaker is annoying altogether (at least, I think it is), I just go

```
modprobe -r pcspkr
```

and add it to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf like this:

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

No more beeps. Ever.

Does not work for bells through /dev/snd/*, obviously

Comment: Newer kernels use snd_pcsp instead, if the above does not work. Try modprobe -r snd_pcsp and blacklist snd_pcsp.

Comment: Throwing the baby out with the bath water!

Comment: I think 'Throwing the baby out with the bath water' would be unplugging the pc speaker ;-)

Comment: +1 This answered my opposite question: "how do I get terminal beeps to work?"

Comment: That's not so much an answer, I would just want the terminal beep off! Not my sound to go away!

Answer (score 23):

Easiest fix: put

```
set prefer-visible-bell on
```

in your `~/.inputrc`.

This however will only work for applications using the readline library (this includes Bash). Other applications may still decide to beep at you.

If you want to disable all beeping, you will have to do it in the terminal. How to do this depends on your terminal. In `xterm` it's option `-vb` (also works in many other terminals, e.g. in rxvt). Most graphical terminals have a config option for this.

Also see the [Visible bell mini-Howto](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Visual-Bell.html) for all the dirty details.

Answer (score 10):

```
$ setterm -blength 0
```

You'll want to add this to your Bash profile.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the `setterm` and GNOME settings solutions already suggested there are the following:

If running X, open an `xterm` and enter `xset b off`.

To disable system bell in Bash startup edit `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` and add the line `set bell-style none` or `set bell-style visual` if you want a screen flash.

There's a good article on this [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-linux-disable-or-turn-off-beep-sound-for-terminal/).

Answer (score 8):

from [cybercity](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-linux-disable-or-turn-off-beep-sound-for-terminal/):

- Open Gnome terminal
- Click on Settings > Preferences > Silence Terminal Bell

Comment: Those sound like the instructions for a KDE application, and don't work exactly right on Gnome Terminal. However you were on the right track.